# Overriding default member(s) of a given type in a function parameter with JSDoc

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jsdoc

Considering the following setup,

```
/**
 * @typedef {generalObject} GeneralObject
 * @type {Object}
 * @property {Object} generalField
 */
var generalObject = {
  generalField : {}
};

/**
 * @typedef {specificObject} SpecificObject
 * @type {GeneralObject}
 * @extends {GeneralObject}
 * @property {Object} foobar
 */
var specificObject = Object.create(generalObject, {
  specificField : {
    value : {}
  }
});

/**
 * @typedef {exampleContainer} Container
 * @type {Object}
 * @property {GeneralObject} object1
 */
var exampleContainer = {
  object1 : Object.create(generalObject)
};
```

We have a container with a field of type `GeneralObject`, and a `SpecificObject` of type `GeneralObject`. Now, with the following functions:

```
/**
 * @param {Container} container
 */
function doSomething(container) {
  container.object1.//Auto-completed with 'generalField'
}

/**
 * @param {Container} container
 * @param {SpecificObject} container.object1
 */
function doSomethingSpecific(container) {
  container.object1.//Not auto-completed with 'specificField'
}
```

The `doSomething` function expects a classic container and works fine, but the `doSomethingSpecific` function expects `container.object1` to be of type `SpecificObject`, while keeping the rest of the `Container` type.

As the comments say, WebStorm's auto-completion won't recognize `container.object1` as `SpecificObject`, but instead as `GeneralObject`.

Is there a way to get this kind of behaviour? If so, is overriding the first `@param` with a second one the right way to do it?